# Working with subsets, as opposed to elements.

Tags: soft-question, notation

Especially in algebraic contexts, we can often work with subsets, as opposed to elements. For instance, in a ring we can define

$$A+B = \{a+b\mid a \in A, b \in B\},\quad -A = \{-a\mid a \in A\}$$

$$AB = \{ab\mid a \in A, b \in B\}$$

and under these definitions, singletons work exactly like elements. For instance, $\{a\}+\{b\} = \{c\}$ iff $a+b=c$.

Now suppose we're working in an *ordered ring*. What should $A \leq B$ mean? I can think of at least two possible definitions.

1. For all $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ it holds that $a \leq b$.
2. There exists $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ such that $a \leq b$.

   Also, a third definition was suggested in the comments:
3. For all $a \in A$ there exists $b \in B$ such that $a \leq b$.

Note that according to all three definitions, we have $\{a\} \leq \{b\}$ iff $a \leq b$. That's because "for all $x \in X$" and "there exists $x \in X$" mean the same thing whenever $X$ is a singleton set.

What's the natural thing to do here? (1), (2), or something else entirely?

Note that our earlier definitions leveraged *existence*. For example: $$A+B = \{x\mid \exists a \in A, b \in B : a+b=x\}.$$

Comment: note that in definition (2) you can have that both $A\le B$ and $B\le A$ for some $A,B$'s. That's gonna be a problem if you want your order to continue being an order on sets (since it's not antisymmetric anymore)

Comment: The first definition feels right to me. I imagine the second isn't very useful.

Comment: @kneidell, you mean for distinct $A$, $B$'s? Like $A = \{0,1,2\},$ $B = \{0,2\}$.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with having a partial order here. That's the natural level of generality anyway.

Comment: For "large" $A,B$ definition (2) will converge on meaninglessness since $A\le B$ for almost all $A,B$.  This type of relation is uncommon.  However (1) will converge on $A,B$ incomparable for almost all $A,B$.  This type of partial order is familiar and useful.  In this sense (2) is the negation of (1).

Comment: May I suggest (3) For all $a\in A$, there exists $b\in B$ with $a\le b$.  This is saying something a bit more interesting than (2), if $A$ has an upper bound.

Comment: @vadim123, hmmm perhaps (3')... $A \leq B$ iff (i) for all $a \in A$ we can find $b \in B$ such that $a \leq b$, and (ii) for all $b \in B$ we can find $a \in A$ such that $a \leq b$. That way, two sets are equal in the usual sense iff they're equal in the sense induced by the equality relation on elements.

Comment: In actual practice the usual meaning of $A\le B$ is your (1).

Comment: "Note that our earlier definitions leveraged *existence*." But the key point is that your earlier definitions were for *operations* and this is for a *relation*. This would support @user18921's idea because $A=B$ is something you already understand in that way.

Answer (score 2):

This question is entirely subjective.  "should" and "natural" mean different things to different people.  When we move toward generality, we gain additional texture and details that we didn't have before.  Ideal numbers (i.e. ideals) have properties that ordinary numbers (i.e. ring elements) do not.  The "right" definition is the one that allows us to prove something interesting.  Absent any context, all of the above are right, and all of the above are wrong.

(1) treats sets as intervals.  $A\le B$ if $\sup A \le \inf B$.  This leads to a partial order rather than a total order.  Perhaps this is what you want, since after all this context is more general.  For nonoverlapping sets, this seems right, but for overlapping sets it's fairly conservative.

(2) is a strange variation of (1).  $A\le B$ if either $\inf A < \sup B$  or $\min A = \max B$ (provided both exist).  For overlapping sets, this will mean that both $A\le B$ and $B\le A$ hold, so the relation fails antisymmetry, which is strange.

(3) treats sets as points, namely their suprema.  $A\le B$ if $\sup A \le \sup B$.  This has the advantage of being a total order, on those sets that are bounded above.

(4) Yiorgos' suggestion is to consider the internal structure of sets; namely to decompose sets as [sumsets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumset).  This looks at entirely different properties of sets.

(5) A commonly used order on sets, not previously mentioned, is inclusion.  That is, $A\le B$ if $A\subseteq B$.  This is a specialization of Yiorgos' order, since he can take $C=\{0\}$.

However, there are a bazillion other orderings we can impose.  For example:

(6) Choose a prime $p$ in your ring, and define $A\le B$ if $\nu_p(\prod A)\le \nu_p(\prod B)$, where $\nu_p$ denotes the [$p$-adic valuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_valuation), extending the definition to infinite products in some way.

None of these are worth anything in isolation, and any of them might be the most important partial order in the world if they happen to solve the problem you're working on.

Comment: +1 for an interesting list of possibilities. However, if you're arguing that asking about the "correct" way to do things is in general useless or irrelevant, I'm going to have to strongly, strongly disagree. It is possible that, in this *particular* case, there is no "right" definition.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

$$
A\le B \quad\text{iff}\quad \text{there exists a set on nonnegative elements $C$, s.t.}\quad
B=A+C.
$$

Comment: That is too restrictive to be useful as a general definition (very few $B$ that dominate $A$ are of the form $A+C$), but it is a property that should be true under any definition.

Answer (score 0):

Since we're talking about *ordered rings*, maybe the ordering could be applicable to each comparison, too. i.e., 
$$ a_n \le b_n \forall a \in A,b \in B$$
if you were to apply this to the sets of even integers (greater than 0) and odd integers it might look like 1<2, 3<4, etc. Of course, cardinality comes into play since you need *n*-elements to exist in both sets. Maybe the caveat could be $n=min([A],[B])$.